# Indexing Python array and skipping

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, indexing

I have a matrix for which I want to do the following in Matlab syntax:

```
M = [M1(1:3:20,1:3:20) M1(21:40,21:40) M1(41:3:70,41:3:70)];
```

So, I want to skip every 3th element for the first 20 element and again skip every 3th element for 41-70 elements, while those in the middle stay the same.

How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python syntax is very similar, but please note that the step size goes at the end of the slicing syntax:

```
import numpy as np
M1 = np.ones((100, 100))
M = [M1[1:20:3,1:20:3], M1[21:40,21:40], M1[41:70:3,41:70:3]]
```